# Is there any norm function on any space such that it is differentiable everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any norm function on any space with $0$ such that it is differentiable everywhere?

---

Euclidean norm is not differentiable at $0$.But Can we prove that no norm function is differentiable at $0$

Answer (score 2):

No norm is differentiable at $0$. Notice that if $f(x)=\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert$ is a norm then on the line $\alpha u$ where $u$ is a unit vector in a vector space then we have:

$$\frac{f(\alpha u)-f(0)}{\alpha}=\frac{\lvert\lvert\alpha u\rvert\rvert}{\alpha}=\text{sgn}(\alpha)\lvert\lvert u\rvert\rvert=\text{sgn}(\alpha)$$

so the function does not have a directional derivative at $0$ and hence cannot be Frechet Differentiable.